# Check if there are errors/exceptions in a batch of Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, testing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there are way to check whether any exceptions occur in a Jupyter notebook (python3)?

I would like to create a git hook that runs all Jupyter notebooks in a certain sub directory and refuses to commit if any exceptions are raised there.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out the [`nbconvert` docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-using-the-python-api-interface) (and don't just copy-paste - the doc examples do things you don't need).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I should have thought of that myself.